# Vue3 reactivity in props breaks when props are de-referenced?

Tags: vue.js, vue-reactivity

Since the variable `editing` loses reactivity to prop changes when the prop is accessed this way, I am wondering how I can fix this so I maintain reactivity to prop changes. I can't use computed property since I will need to update the `editing.value` in other scenarios.

```
const editing = ref(false)
editing.value = !props.modelValue || !props.obscureInitialValue;
```

I can setup a watcher to watch for the prop change and then update the editing.value. But I am wondering if there are any better ways? I have also considered using toRefs but then won't I run into the same issue.

For eg-

```
const modelValue = toRef(props.modelValue)
const obscureInitialValue = toRef(props.obscureInitialValue)

const editing = ref(!modelValue || !obscureInitialValue);
```

Wouldn't the above just cause the same broken link to prop changes?

Comment: To me, a watcher just seems to be the only plausible fit for me. Unless there is a better opinion, I will use a watcher to watch for the prop change and then update the editing ref.

Comment: It's unknown how it's supposed to work. You may not need "editing" internal state if it's supposed to duplicate modelValue value at any moment

Comment: I need it as a internal state because editing state needs to update when a edit icon is clicked, so have to do editing.value = true when the user clicks on the edit icon

Comment: I mean that edit state could be in a parent only and be updated through two-way binding. Most times it's solved like that. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve if you still have doubts about that